# String concatenation based on best practices

Tags: c#

I have a string,

```
string ij = "/alwaysSame09102012/myThing.aspx?asdasd=99&Urasdl=scashdasdeasdmeasds/tasdigaesdr1/gasdoasdveasdasdrnaasdancasde/eamsdeasdetiasdasdnagsds/tasidgeasdr1masdeetasdasd11180,/reasdMeasdetMe2as0d1asd0/asrdganasdiseasdasdgeasdetasdiasdngaasdsd.aasdspafsxasdffas?asdsdlaieasdnedtfe=asdsafaser1meafswedfhfdget111ertert80"
```

Now i just need to change the first "alwaysSame09102012" with "always2013forever".

I know i can do something like this,

```
string ij = "/alwaysSame09102012/myThing.aspx?asdasd=99&Urasdl=scashdasdeasdmeasds/tasdigaesdr1/gasdoasdveasdasdrnaasdancasde/eamsdeasdetiasdasdnagsds/tasidgeasdr1masdeetasdasd11180,/reasdMeasdetMe2as0d1asd0/asrdganasdiseasdasdgeasdetasdiasdngaasdsd.aasdspafsxasdffas?asdsdlaieasdnedtfe=asdsafaser1meafswedfhfdget111ertert80"

string[] c = ij.split['/'];

string finalString =  ij.replace( "/" + c[0] + "/", "/" + "always2013forever" + "/");
```

This is my logic but no working, please help,

only constant in my string is  `"/alwaysSame09102012/"` which i need to replace

**Update**

**

- *What if I got this "alwaysSame09102012"  in at of my query string,
  that's why I don't want to use replace.*

**

Comment: What about `string finalString = ij.Replace("alwaysSame09102012","always2013forever");` ?

Comment: what's wrong with `string.Replace` or do you not know about that?

Comment: _but no working_ -- you should also include the expected _and_ actual output.

Comment: and why did you go to all the trouble of splitting the string to get c[0] if it is constant?

Comment: thanks but i can have "alwaysSame09102012" in my query string 2 times, how would i make sure it's first one i need to replace. also it's bank software if i don't program it properly ATM machine will not work properly and you will get less money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Ex:

```
var goodStr = ij.Replace("alwaysSame09102012", "always2013forever");
```

The reason your answer does not work is because `c[0]` is going to be `""`. The value you are looking for (e.g. 'alwaysSame09102012') is going to be in `c[1]`.

Comment: thanks but what if i got alwaysSame09102012   twice in string

Comment: Check the accepted answer for this question (it is essentially what you need!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201595/c-sharp-simplest-way-to-remove-first-occurance-of-a-substring-from-another-str

Comment: Here, this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 1):

```
string ij = "/alwaysSame09102012/myThing.aspx?asdasd=99&Urasdl=scashdasdeasdmeasds/tasdigaesdr1/gasdoasdveasdasdrnaasdancasde/eamsdeasdetiasdasdnagsds/tasidgeasdr1masdeetasdasd11180,/reasdMeasdetMe2as0d1asd0/asrdganasdiseasdasdgeasdetasdiasdngaasdsd.aasdspafsxasdffas?asdsdlaieasdnedtfe=asdsafaser1meafswedfhfdget111ertert80"

string newString = ij.Replace("alwaysSame09102012","always2013forever");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string ReplaceFirst (string source, string old_substring, string new_substring)
{
    var position = source.IndexOf(old_substring);
    return (position < 0)
        ? source
        : source.Substring(0, position) + new_substring + source.Substring(position + old_substring.Length);
}
```

Usage:

```
var new_string = ReplaceFirst("/alwaysSame09102012/myThing...", "alwaysSame09102012","always2013forever");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the URI classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx

This will give you more flexibility, and prevent you from escaping problems etc.